# How is generic information used by the compiler if generic static methods are called?

Tags: java, generics

I have a question regarding generic types. I have written my own iterator type and would like to return an empty iterator if there is nothing to iterate over.

The following code works,

```
@Override
public Iterator<MyType> iterator() {
    final Iterator<MyType> iter = Collections.emptyIterator();
    return count > 0 ? new MyIterator() : iter;
}
```

however, it does not work, if written in one line like this:

```
@Override
public Iterator<MyType> iterator() {
    return count > 0 ? new MyIterator() : Collections.emptyIterator();
}
```

I get an error and have to cast the type to solve it:

```
@Override
public Iterator<MyType> iterator() {
    return (Iterator<MyType>)(count > 0 ? new MyIterator() : Collections.emptyIterator());
}
```

This cast leads then to a unchecked warning, in the first example there is no warning.

When I move the cast to the inside, it does not work either:

```
@Override
public Iterator<MyType> iterator() {
    return count > 0 ? new EdgeIterator() : (Iterator<MyType>) Collections.emptyIterator();
}
```

My question now is: why can't the compiler decide that the types are correct in the latter examples, but in the first. Why does the cast in variant 3 work, but not in the last one? The variants are all are basically the same in my impression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work, use this syntax :

```
 return Collections.<MyType>emptyIterator();
```

This is how to give the generic to a static method.

If you call `Collections.emptyIterator();` then it returns a `Iterator<Object>` which is incompatible with your return type.

You also cannot cast because `Iterator<MyType>` **does not extends** `Iterator<Object>`.

Comment: Works like a charm. But this syntax really looks weird. I have tried "Collections<MyType>.emptyIterator()", but that was wrong. However, I am still interested why the first case does not create a warning then.

Comment: @kap In the first case, Java can infer the generic type. It is explained here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html There is an example with `Collections.emptyList();`